# How can I simulate packet loss using tc netem?

Tags: filter, controls, network-traffic

I am trying to simulate a 5% packet loss using the tc tool at server port 1234. Here are my steps -

```
sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 flowid 1:1 match ip dport 1234 0xffff
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 1: netem loss 5%
```

There are no errors during the above commands. But when I send any TCP traffic to that port, there is no packet loss observed. 
What am I doing wrong in the above commands ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See https://serverfault.com/a/841865/342799 for similar case.

Commands I have in my testing rig to drop 5.5% of packets:

```
# tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio priomap 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
# tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem loss 5.5% 25%
# DST_IP=1.2.3.4/32
# tc filter add \
  dev eth0 \
  parent 1: \
  protocol ip \
  prio 1 \
  u32 \
    match ip dst $DST_IP \
  flowid 1:1
```

To confirm, run:

```
# ping -f -c 1000 $DST_IP
```

before and after this setup.

Note: Almost all hosting providers start throttling your traffic if you do lot of flood pings.